# asp Button not working if Response.Write is used in the code

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, I have been working with asp.net since a while now and I came across this bug that I still don't know the cause of.

My aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="Incomes and Outcomes" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="IncomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="AccountingSite.IncomePage" EnableEventValidation="false"%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Res/display.css"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div class="cont">
 <div class="text-center">
    <p class="box-main">Incomes and Outcomes</p>
</div>
<br />

<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col50 b1">
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="Description" ID="inputDesc"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col50 b1">
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="Value" ID="inputValue"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col50 b1 autocomplete">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="Customer" ID="inputCustomer"
            AutoCompleteType="Disabled" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
    <br />
<div class="text-center">
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="sub topBtn" ID="AddBtn"
        OnClick="AddIncome_Click" CausesValidation="false"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Remove selected" CssClass="sub-remove topBtn"
        OnClick="RemoveIncome_Click" CausesValidation="false"/>
</div>
<br />
<br />
  <div class="row text-center">
    <label style="font-size: 18px;">Date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="inputDate" runat="server" onchange="ValueChanged();"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SOME_BTN" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Test"
        OnClick="SOME_BTN_Click" CssClass="asdf" CausesValidation="false"/>
  </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="colThird topRow text-center f1">
            <label>Description</label>
        </div>
        <div class="colThird topRow text-center f1">
            <label>+</label>
        </div>
        <div class="colThird topRow text-center f1">
            <label>-</label>
        </div>
    </div>
                      <%
                          Response.Write("<h1>Test</h1>");
                          //Write();
                      %>
</div>
<script>
    function ValueChanged() {
        var sb = document.getElementById("<%=SOME_BTN.ClientID %>");
        sb.click();
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

The cs file:

```
    public partial class IncomePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    bool running = false;
    public double pos = 0;
    public double neg = 0;
    private static string[] Customers;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main.CurrentPage = IPage.IncomePage;
        if (Session["Logged"] == null)
        {
            //Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
            //return;
        }
    }

    protected void AddIncome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Send(this, "test");
        
    }

    protected void RemoveIncome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Send(this, "test");
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        
    }

    public double GetBalance()
    {
        return Main.GetBalance();
    }

    protected void SOME_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(inputDate.Value != null)
        {
            var x = DateTime.Parse(inputDate.Value).ToString().Split(' ')[0];
            Response.Redirect("IncomePage.aspx?d="+x);
        }
    }

}
```

The method Main.Send() runs alert() in javascript code, so it serves debugging purpose.

It seems that whenever I add Response.Write() to the aspx file (as shown in the code above), asp buttons stop working so the click events do not fire at all. Strange enough, the code runs perfectly fine in my other aspx files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Response write if you don't need to, it messes up a lot of things, like rendering and stylesheets. Instead maybe think about setting text of a label and displaying that label (Visible = true) when you need to. You could also use alert boxes via

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alrt", "alert('+ " label.Text + "');", true);
```

You can call you function from code behind as well

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "func", "functioName();", true);
```

Comment: The problem is that this page I am working with is dynamic in the way that it creates a bunch of divs and elements based on a database so it basically displays what the database contains. The Main.Send method does exactly what you mentioned above.